# An example of the first/second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry

I have some trouble understanding the first/second fundamental form, so I guess a worked-out example would really help.

Let's say for the graph of a function $g(x,y)$ with respect to the natural chart. What are the matrices for the first fundamental form, the second fundamental form, the differential of the Gauss map, and the Gaussian curvature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural parametrization is $F(x,y)= (x,y,g(x,y))$.

So $F'_x=(1,0,g'_x) ; F'_y=(0,1, g'_y)$.

Then ${ds}^2= (1+{g'_x}^2){dx}^2$+$2g'_xg'_y dx dy+(1+{g'_y}^2 ){dy}^2$.

A normal vector is $F'_x \wedge F'_y=(-g'_x,-g'_y,1)$,

The Gauss map is $N(x,y)=-{1\over \sqrt {1+{g'_x}^2+{g'_x}^2}}( g'_x, g'_y,-1)$.

The second form is obtained while deriving $N(x,y)$, which yields an ugly formula.

The case where $g'_x(0,0)=g'_y(0,0)=0$ (ie the surface is horizontal) is nice and easy, the second form is given by a immediate computation $ g''(0,0)= -Hess(g)(0,0)$. Note the sign -. For instance the hemi-sphere $z= \sqrt {R^2-x^2-y^2}= R-{x^2+y^2\over 2R}+o(x^2+y^2)$ has positive curvature $1/R^2$, as $g''(0,0)=-{1\over R} Id$.

Comment: I guess the Gauss map should be $N(x,y)=\frac{( g'_x, g'_y,-1)}{-\sqrt {1+{g'_x}^2+{g'_x}^2}}$?

Comment: Yes, a typo, sorry.